# Getting ' TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str' when trying to retrieve keys from series of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

I am trying to get the keys from a serie that contains dictionaries.
My code is:

```
a = [{'uid': 46}, {'uid': 47}]
print (a['uid'])
```

but this throws '
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

what I want to achieve is making this code work:

```
ids = [a["id"] for a in df["driven"]]
```

which would ideally give me [46, 47].

But I get the same TypeError message.

df["driven"] looks something similar to:
[{'id': 46}, {'id': 47}] and is of type pandas.series

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a list,dont have str index like `uid`,you need to access the list dict element to get `uid`
code:

```
a = [{'uid': 46}, {'uid': 47}]
print([element["uid"] for element in a])
```

result:

```
[46, 47]
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are trying to do something as below.

```
lst = ['a','b','c']
print(lst['a'])
```

When indexing a string, you have to and should give only integers. Though I see what you want to do. The below code will iterate through the list, and then find the value of each key in the given dictionary.

```
a = [{'uid': 46}, {'uid': 47}]
print([dicts['uid'] for dicts in a])
```

output

```
[46, 47]
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I did realize that. It was basically nested so I needed to do an extra layer of un-nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is in a list and you can get the element from it using indexing like `a[0],a[1]`. You are actually fetching from the list first, then a dictionary.

```
a = [{'uid': 46}, {'uid': 47}]
print ([val['uid'] for val in a])
```

Output:

```
[46,47]
```